# Shopware 6 theme development - exclude specific Storefront styling or SCSS file

Tags: sass, themes, shopware

I have a CSS selector that gets a lot of styles from the built-in `Storefront` theme. I don't want to use any of those styles. Do I have to override/reset each single CSS property in my theme, or is there a way to exclude one specific `Storefront` SCSS file from compilation? Or even better, exclude that specific CSS selector?

Comment: Good question, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a built in way to do this.

You might want to try to decorate the following method in a plugin and clear out the existing styles in the array

https://github.com/shopware/storefront/blob/fc16b8db664d077807073397b04ee3c56b7e3735/Theme/ThemeFileResolver.php#L27

Comment: I will give this a try as soon as I got time. Many thanks!